# Преимущества низкоуровневых функций над высокоуроевными

Tags: c++

Я начинающий программист. Задали написать программу и выяснить в чём разница низкоуровневых функций над теми же Qфункциями в QT или же высокоуровневыми в visual studio. Можете объяснить какие преимущества у одних функций над другими, с примерами низкоуровневыми и их высокоуровневыми аналогами на Qt или Visual? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а можете привести пример высокоуровневой функции и низкоуровневой, т.к. непонятно о чем речь

Comment: Я сам не знаю, поэтому вас и спрашиваю.
Преподаватель сказал, что функции по типу QFile -- высокоуровневые, а frpintf -- низкоуровневые. Я сейчас вообще в ступоре из-за этого.

Comment: Я вижу разницу между printf и write (это в Linux) или WriteFile(в Windows), первая реализована в userspace(по другому,вы сами можешь её реализовать если захочете), а другие это системные вызовы которые исполняются в пространстве ядра (и вы их сами не можете реализовать).
А так по мне QFile(в QT) и FILE (в С) не критически различаются, (оба (точно не уверен) обертки над file discriptor(в Linux) или Handle(в Windows), просто QFile представляет больше функционала. С другой стороны можно сказать что FILE более низкоуровневый т.к предоставляет меньше абстракций чем QFILE,но я плохо разбираюсь в QT

Comment: Идея QT - кросплатформенность. Независимо от ОС, например, код для работы с TCP-сокетом соберется и под windows и под linux. Более того, класс для работы с сокетами унаследован от одного и того же класса. что и QFile, так что это просто  устройство ввода-вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то низкоуровнивые функции выполняют меньше объём работы чем высокоуровнивые. Например функция задать цвет пикселя будет мение высокоуровневой чем функция нарисовать красный квадрат.